# how to normalize python list with different length to a given length?

Tags: python, list, normalization

I have a python series. The series contains lists with different lengths.

```
0       [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, ...
1                                                  [2, 2]
2                                                     [2]
3       [1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, ...
4           [1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
5                                            [2, 0, 1, 1]
6                                                  [2, 2]
7                                      [0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2]
8                                            [2, 0, 2, 0]
9       [2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, ...
10                                                 [1, 0]
11                         [1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1]
12      [1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, ...
13      [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, ...
14      [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, ...
15                            [1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]
```

What I want to do is to measure the Volatility of these lists. As far as I'm concerned, I need to do the normalization work(which means all these lists will share the same length) before measuring. I think parsing each list precentagewise plausibility is a good choice.Sadly, I don't know how to manage it.
Maybe the first step is to transform lists to a given length. Sec step is to calculate the new score in each percentile(something like max_pooling avg? I don't know^).How to extract items from lists by peicentile?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: All you posted is a (weak) program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your premise that they all need to be the same length to measure their volatility. What exactly do you mean by the term and why do you think making them all the same length helps?